# finding output to a simple but tricky program

Tags: c, output, expression, implicit-conversion

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
   float a=5,b=2;
   int c,d;
   c=a%b;
   d=a/2;
   printf("%d\n",d);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Could you say what exactly your question is?

Comment: Are you asking for the output of this program?

Comment: Simple but tricky?

Comment: What are `b` and `c` used for? You are just printing `d` which is `a/2`

Comment: The output is `2` as 5.0/2.0= 2.5 which is truncated to 2.

Answer (score 2):

The program is incorrect because the operator % is not defined for float numbers.

From the C Standard (6.5.5 Multiplicative operators)

> 2 Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type. **The operands of
>   the % operator shall have integer type.**

As for this statement

```
d=a/2;
```

then there is a conversion from the expression with the float type `a /2`  to the type of the left-hand side operand that has the type `int`. So the value of `d` will be equal to `2`.

Pehaps you mean a program similar to the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 5, b = 2;
    int c, d;

    c = a % b;
    d = a / b;

    printf( "d = %d, c = %d\n", d, c );

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the program output is

```
d = 2, c = 1
```

Instead of the two variables `c` and `d` and two expressions with the operators `/` and `%` you could use the standard function `div` declared in the header `<stdlib.h>`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 5, b = 2;

    div_t result = div( a, b );

    printf( "quotient = %d, remainder = %d\n", result.quot, result.rem );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
quotient = 2, remainder = 1
```

Comment: Vlad, would that mean that the operands are converted to int types?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No there will not be a conversion.

Comment: No they won't. They generate a compiler error message.